# Retrieve data from database without printing

Tags: prolog

How do I retrieve data from the database to use it in a condition, but I don't want to print it the console.
Problem I am doing is to retrieve a child from a database whose parents age differ by 15 years.

This is the code I am using which works and prints the year of both parents.

```
family(person(_,_,date(_,_,Year1),_),
       person(_,_,date(_,_,Year2),_),
       [person(Name,Surname,_,_)|Y]), abs(Year1-Year2) >= 15.
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a predicate rule (in a source file) using the query as its body. For example:

```
child_with_parents_age_gap(Gap, Name, Surname) :-
    family(
        person(_,_,date(_,_,Year1),_),
        person(_,_,date(_,_,Year2),_),
        [person(Name,Surname,_,_)| _]
    ),
    abs(Year1-Year2) >= Gap.
```